# Generating a Random Location Within a Given Range (that can be positive or negative)

Tags: java, random, location, bukkit, radius

Currently I have this code.

```
public static Location getRandomLocation(int min, int max, World w) {
    int x = CommonUtils.randomInt(min, max);
    int y = 255;
    int z = CommonUtils.randomInt(min, max);
    while (w.getBlockAt(x, y, z).getType() == Material.AIR) {
        y--;
    }
    return w.getBlockAt(x, y + 1, z).getLocation();
}
```

I want to generate random values for the x and z coordinates that can also be negative. The problem I into though, was that I need the absolute value of the  numbers to still be greater than the `min` value even if the actual number is not.

More simply put, right now it can only generate random locations between the `min` and `max`. How would I also include numbers that are between `-min` and `-max`?

Comment: Do you only want the locations to be one block across?

Comment: @kmecpp Lets just say I want a random x,z that can be higher than max, lower than min, so it could be 1000,1000 but not 999,999 can be -1000,-1000 but not -999.-999

Comment: A little confused by your pictures... do you want just a single location or multiple locations? Like in a ring?

Comment: 1 location than can be 1000 or more,1000 or more | -1000 or more,-1000 or more but cant be 999 or less,999 or less | -999 or less,-999 or less

Comment: Could you make an example min max and provide a list of acceptable values and then a list of non acceptable values so I know exactly what you want?

Comment: Accepted: from 1000 to 5000 or -1000 to -5000 Denied: from 999 to 0 or from -999 to 0

Comment: and the problem with your code is that its only working for the positive numbers?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem!

Comment: @kemcpp http://pastebin.com/pmi08Efj Here, I made a method that is really inefficient, but maybe you could make it work better. Made a mistake: `x > -min` `z > -min`

Comment: I posted an answer but I recommend editing your question to clarify and explain exactly what you wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, now I get what you want. You already have basically working code then if you just need to make it work for negative numbers. A simple fix would be to just add a random sign onto the already generated numbers. Something like this should work fine:

```
public static Location getRandomLocation(int min, int max, World world) {
    int x = CommonUtils.randomInt(-max, max);//Random x coord
    int z;
    if (Math.abs(x) < min) {
        z = CommonUtils.randomInt(min, max);//If x coord is less than the minimum choose a z coord that is within range
        if (new Random().nextBoolean()) {//Top or bottom of range
            z = -z;
        }
    } else {
        z = CommonUtils.randomInt(-max, max);//Else choose any z coord
    }
    int y = 255;
    while (world.getBlockAt(x, y, z).getType() == Material.AIR) {
        y--;
    }
    return world.getBlockAt(x, y + 1, z).getLocation();
}
```

Comment: Another problem, now they are being generated at TOP RIGHT, TOP LEFT, BOTTOM RIGHT, BOTTOM LEFT. But not at LEFT, RIGHT, TOP, BOTTOM.

Comment: http://i.gyazo.com/cece1143ee7980cdd2594fd56d049d36.png The red boxes are the locations that the locations are being generated.

Comment: @Danielngx-development Can you post more code so I know exactly what you're doing with the method?

Comment: @Danielngx-development ahhh, slightly more difficult than I originally thought. I updated my original answer but you might just want to think about teleporting players to any random location. This box thing seems unnecessarily complicated :P

Comment: The problem is, The random tp meaning is to teleport a player to a random locations from spawn. If I set it to a 1 big box, Random teleporting back to spawn doesn't seem so good.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to add on to what kmecpp said as I can't comment, do not loop through all of the Y blocks to check if they are air or not. This longer to do than using `getHighestBlockYAt(x, z);`. This will return the Y location of the highest block at the world at that location. For example:

```
//Get your Random location with random x and y, and set the y to something like 5.
int newY = getServer().getWorld(worldName).getHighestBlockYAt(loc.getX(), loc.getZ());
Location newLoc = new Location(loc.getWorld(), loc.getX(), newY, loc.getZ());
```

Regarding Random Teleporting in a Range with Negative and Positive numbers, here is my code that I use on my server. (Note that this will teleport them into spawn)

This will teleport the player to a random location in a 12000 block wide square with 0,0 being the center.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int max = 6000;
int min = -6000;
int locX = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
int locZ = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
Location loc = new Location(getServer().getWorld("wild"), locX, 20, locZ);
loc.setY(getServer().getWorld("wild").getHighestBlockYAt(locX, locZ));
Block b = getServer().getWorld("world").getBlockAt((int) loc.getX(), (int) loc.getY() - 1, (int) loc.getZ());
while(b.getType() == Material.LAVA || b.getType() == Material.WATER){
    locX = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    locZ = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    loc = new Location(getServer().getWorld("wild"), locX, 20, locZ);
    loc.setY(getServer().getWorld("wild").getHighestBlockYAt(locX, locZ));
    b = getServer().getWorld("world").getBlockAt((int) loc.getX(), (int), loc.getY() - 1, (int) loc.getZ());
}
return loc;
```

If you want to make it so that they don't teleport into spawn, you need to set another six ints, spawnXMin, spawnXMax, and corresponding ones for Y and Z. Then just do a simple check:

```
int spawnXMin = 100, spawnXMax = 200, spawnYMin = 0, spawnYMax = 255, spawnZMin = 150, spawnZMax = 250;
while(!(loc.getX() < spawnXMax && loc.getX() > spawnXMin && loc.getY() < spawnYMax && loc.getY() > spawnMin && loc.getZ() < spawnZMax && loc.getZ() > spawnZMin)) {
    //Player is not in spawn so redo above while code
}
//Found Location!
//Teleport Player
```